# Wrong behavior with angularjs service?

Tags: angularjs, promise

i have write one service like that :

```
pinholeAdminServices.factory('ServiceChannel', ['Channel', '$httpWrapper' , '$route', '$q' , function (Channel, $httpWrapper, $route, $q) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        'MultiChannelsLoader': function (params) {
            params = params || $route.current.params;
            var delay = $q.defer();
            Channel.query(params, function (response) {
                delay.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                delay.reject(error);
            });
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

and after that i have change the place of `var delay = $q.defer();`  in the top of service like that :

```
Services.factory('ServiceChannel', ['Channel', '$httpWrapper' , '$route', '$q' , function (Channel, $httpWrapper, $route, $q) {
    'use strict';
   var delay = $q.defer();
    return {
        'MultiChannelsLoader': function (params) {
            params = params || $route.current.params;
            Channel.query(params, function (response) {
                delay.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                delay.reject(error);
            });
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

and the application behavior became totally wrong. can anyone explain what's the difference between the two part's of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates *one* deferred for *every* ServiceChannel usage.

This means, that when you call `MultiChannelsLoader` it will use the same promise each time.

A promise is an abstraction over a *one time* calculation. After it is resolved a promise can not change its state.

```
var d = $q.defer();
d.resolve("Foo"); // d will forever be remained in fulfilled state, with "Foo"
```

Imagine that resolve is implemented as:

```
resolve: function(){
    if(pending){ // not resolved yet
        pending = undefined; // change state to not pending.
    }
}
```

Oh wait, [it actually is](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/58f5da86645990ef984353418cd1ed83213b111e/src/ng/q.js#L207-L223). The promise specification is also crystal clear about this:

> When fulfilled, a promise: must not transition to any other state.
>   When rejected, a promise: must not transition to any other state.

([reference](http://promisesaplus.com/))